# $\pi$-base of topological space

Tags: general-topology

I've recently came across the $\pi$-weight which is the cardinality of the smallest $\pi$-base of topological space. Unfortunately I've never heard of such thing as $\pi$-base and can't find any article which has the definition of it. What exactly is a $\pi$-base?

Comment: Actually, $\pi w(X)$ is the maximum of $\aleph_0$ and the minimum cardinality of a $\pi$-base for the space. See for instance I. Juhász, *Cardinal Functions in Topology*, Mathematical Centre Tracts 34, 1971, or R. Hodel’s chapter *Cardinal Functions I* in *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*, K. Kunen & J.E. Vaughan, eds., 1984.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one I know for sure is

> Stover, Derrick. "On $\pi $-metrizable spaces, their continuous images and products." Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae 50.1 (2009): 153-162.
> [link](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/133423/CommentatMathUnivCarolRetro_50-2009-1_14.pdf)

From the second sentence of the intro:

> Recall that for a space $X$ a collection of nonempty open sets $\Theta$ is called a $\pi$-base if for every nonempty open set $\mathcal O$, there exists a $\mathcal U\in\Theta$ such that $\mathcal U\subset \mathcal O$.

This is confirmed also in [another solution on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/386176/29335).

It also appears in Wikipedia's glossary of topology with the citation:
`Hart, Nagata, Vaughan Sect. d-22, page 227` which seems to refer to

> Hart, Klaas Pieter, Jun-iti Nagata, and Jerry E. Vaughan. Encyclopedia of general topology. Elsevier, 2003.